# Update a deleted timeline item

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/update) does not specify it but ...

If a Glass user deletes a timeline item, can an authorized Glassware service use the timeline id of the deleted item and perform an update operation and have timeline item re-inserted into the Glass user's timeline with the same timeline id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the user has deleted the timeline item, only a tombstone remains in the API to notify the Glassware.

Any requests to this timeline item aside from `GET` will yield a `404 Not Found` response status.